# Potential leak of an object stored into 'name'

Tags: ios, objective-c, contacts

Here is my code:

```
[ NSUInteger peopleCounter = 0; //set a initial value as ZERO.

//Create custom Contacts list
for (peopleCounter = 0; peopleCounter < [arrayOfAllPeople count]; peopleCounter++) {

    ABRecordRef thisPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef) [arrayOfAllPeople objectAtIndex:peopleCounter]; // get every person record one by one.

    NSString *name = (__bridge NSString *) ABRecordCopyCompositeName(thisPerson); //get a person name

    ABMultiValueRef number = ABRecordCopyValue(thisPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty); //get a person number

    //optimize a phone numbers
    for (NSUInteger emailCounter = 0; emailCounter < ABMultiValueGetCount(number); emailCounter++) {

        NSString *email = (__bridge NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(number, emailCounter);
        ][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use method with *copy* in its name like `ABRecordCopyCompositeName` that is returning Core Foundation object like `CFStringRef` you should think about memory management, as ARC is not working unless you tell it how situation should be handled.

In your case you should use `__bridge_transfer` instead of `__bridge`:

```
NSString *name = (__bridge_transfer NSString *) ABRecordCopyCompositeName(thisPerson); //get a person name
```

so `ABRecordCopyCompositeName` result lifetime will be linked to `name` variable lifetime.

Note `ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex` in your example too.